# What is the use of DISPLAY variable in UNIX

Tags: unix, remote-access, putty, remote-desktop

In my project one of my team member using a remote linux machine using putty
lator on i got the same credentials and start working lator the first person asked me which command you running which file you opening
please set DISPLAY variable and he helped me to set but i did nt understand why and how he got to know that i am modifying or opening any file?

what is the need of display variable while access remote unix machine via putty

please clarify

Comment: Your question has been answered here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/432255/what-is-display-environment-variable

Comment: Agree with above AND this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related site http://askubuntu.com. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it there. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.